# Cooliris wall fed by Picassa web albums?

Tags: photo, photo-gallery, cooliris

I am trying to expose picassa web album by using Picassa web albums.

Following example creates wall with only 2 pictures which represents 2 album main photos:

```
<object id="o" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
  width="600" height="450">
<param name="movie" value="http://apps.cooliris.com/embed/cooliris.swf" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
  src="http://apps.cooliris.com/embed/cooliris.swf"
  flashvars="feed=api://picasaweb.google.com/?user=davidinjp"
  width="600" 
  height="450"
  allowFullScreen="true"
  allowScriptAccess="always">
</embed>
</object>
```

How it's possible to show all pictures from all albums? Seems like Cooliris does not support this, using Media RSS cross domain issue arises:

```
<object id="o" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
  width="600" height="450">
<param name="movie" value="http://apps.cooliris.com/embed/cooliris.swf" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
  src="http://apps.cooliris.com/embed/cooliris.swf"
  flashvars="feed=http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/davidinjp?alt=rss&kind=photo&hl=en_GB&access=public"
  width="600" 
  height="450"
  allowFullScreen="true"
  allowScriptAccess="always">
</embed>
</object>
```

Coolris reference:
http://www.cooliris.com/developer/reference/media-site-apis/

---

**@jeffamaphone** Thanks, this is what I've done. I have created simple PHP that mirrors feed on my host:

```
<?php
$content= file_get_contents('http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/USERNAME?alt=rss&kind=photo&hl=en_GB&access=public');

echo $content;
?>
```

Added crossdomain.xml.
Pointed feed to local PHP mirroring script.

Comment: What prevents you from using a CrossDomain.xml file?

Comment: The RSS feed is from Picassa WEB, I cannot upload the XML on picassa web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately what you want to do doesn't have very good support in the Cooliris embed wall.  What is supported (for Picasa) is:

- Get photos of user (grid of albums displayed)
- Get photos of user from a specific album
- Get photos matching a search term

The good news is we have tentatively scheduled these improvements to Picasa support in an upcoming release (though you know how things can change in Software development).

In the mean time, if you have personal hosting available, the dirty work-around is to make a duplicate of the feed, setup crossdomain.xml to work with *.cooliris.com and pull it from there. Not really optimal, but it will work until we add the support you need.

Answer (score 1):

And to get the full out of that code, you should add a &max-results=1000 after the access=public.
It took me 2 hours to get that :D